# Two elements in jQuery find() and If conditional

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I want to apply a statement if specific values of two cells in my table exist, but I don't know how to do that statement.Than

```
$(function() {
    $("#pizarra #trPizarra").each(function() {
        var filon = $(this).find('#tdEdo, #tdImg').text();

        if (filon == "listo") {
            alert('LISTO');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Use OR condition. `if ($(this).find('#tdEdo').text() === 'listo' || $(this).find('#tdImg').text() === 'listo')`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tushar. It works! In case the cell `#tdImg` have two possible values. Do you know how apply that in same statement?

Comment: I suppose with Switch statement instead of If. Thank you, I appreciate your attention and time. See you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution. The || operator will do it for you. Hope it helps!

```
$(function() {
 $("#pizarra #trPizarra").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('#tdEdo').text() === 'listo' || $(this).find('#tdImg').text() === 'listo'){
        alert("listo");
    }
 });
});
```

**Here's solution to your second question:**

```js
$(function() {
   $(".someClass").each(function() {
    if($(this).find("td#ID1").text() === "text1"){
      alert("found text1");
    }
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Header</th>
    <th scope="col">Header</th>
    <th id = "#tdImg" scope="col" colspan="2">Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class = "someClass">
    <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id = "ID1">text1</td>
    <td id = "ID2">text2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @HenryDev!! I ask you the same question that I asked Tushar.  In case the cell `#tdImg` have two possible values. Do you know how apply that in same statement?

Comment: @Emm I'm not sure what you're table looks like but I've updated my answer to give you a hint on how to access cells inside a single cell. Glad it helped!

Comment: Your explanation is very clear but maybe my question not. I will try to be more clear and use your example for that (and excuse my english please). In the cell with text1 the value it's constant, but in the cell with text2 have two different possible values (text2 or text3), and I want that the statement ask for text1 AND text2 or text3. That is to say that two values they match to call the alert, but in the second cell there are two possibilities (text2 or text3). I don't know if I'm clear, I'm sorry.

Comment: I already resolved it. Thank you very much really. Your answers were a great help.